# How to create image slider with rounded bottom image using react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to create image slider like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOQYz.png) with rounded bottom image?

Answer (score 0):

Use this https://github.com/nick/react-native-carousel

Its a simple lib where you can set BorderRadius as default prop